# excel autofill numbers for specially value

Tags: excel, autofill

I have a problem with filling numbers in cells. I have a cell with a number like 12,and now I want 12 rows under that cell, show 1 to 12

Like this picture

[image]

Comment: What you tried yet? You should show your own effort to solve the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `SEQUENCE()` function. Try  like below.

```
=SEQUENCE(A1)
```

`SEQUENCE()` is available on <kbd>ExcelO365</kbd>. So, if you do not have <kbd>ExcelO365</kbd> then try below legacy formula.

```
=IF(ROW($A1)>A$1,"",ROW($A1))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, Your solution, solved my problem

Comment: @MaryamGhafourian Glad to know.